# Can a loop be expressed by only the sequence of statements and the choice of statements?

Tags: programming-languages, computation-models, programming-paradigms

The theorem of structured programming says that any algorithm can be expressed by those three control structures:

1. Sequence
2. Selection
3. Iteration

Isn't it possible to rewrite any loop using a finite sequence of statements and choice between statements? Isn't this what compilers do? Can't we thus omit the third structure and stay equally expressive?

Answer (score 4):

I convinced myself that this is not possible, I was indeed mixing up the *selection* structure with *conditional jumps*; but they're not equally expressive.

The *conditional jump* is as powerful as both *selection* and *iteration* together; this is what compilers use to rewrite both *choice* statements and *loop* statements.

As a counterexample for rewriting any loop using only the first two control structures, think of an infinite loop. This can not be rewritten using only *sequence* and *selection* while it can be rewritten using *sequence* and *conditional jumps*. So, we would lose expressiveness if we went without *iterations*.

---

Addendum to clear up the terminology:

1. *Sequence*
2. *Selection* (synonymous to *choice*), for example IF or SWITCH
3. *Iteration* (synonymous to *loop*), for example WHILE or FOR